# alias wont work - embedding a quoted string in an alias definition

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ksh, zsh

Im trying to make an alias on my mac terminal in zsh shell.

some info when i do echo $SHELL i get /bin/zsh   proving im using the zsh shell.

mac has a command you can use to open things in chrome like this :

```
open -a "google chrome" myfile.html
```

I need to make an alias of this but it wont work but other aliases work.
i would like the alias to run like this

```
chrome myfile.html
```

here is my alias file:

```
alias x="echo \'y "
alias chrome="open -a \'google chrome\' "
```

so if i run x at the prompt y does get outputed but if i run chrome at the command line it says it cant find the file.  Do i have to use xargs or something ?

Comment: As an aside: `$SHELL` _always_ reflects your _default_ shell, not necessarily the one you're currently running. A simple way of determining the executable running the current shell is `ps -o comm= -p $$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: This answer applies not only to `zsh`, but to `bash` and `ksh` as well.

Try:

```
alias chrome='open -a "Google Chrome"'
```

By **using *single* quotes around the entire definition** (which is **generally preferable** when defining an alias, so as to prevent premature expansion of the string at alias *definition* time rather than at *execution* time), you can **use *double* quotes inside without escaping**.

---

The **problem with your definition** was that `\'` literally became part of the alias (rather than just `'`) - **there is no need to escape `'` in a double-quoted string literal**.

Thus, you can also use the following (but, as stated, using single quotes to enclose the entire definition is preferable):

```
alias chrome="open -a 'Google Chrome'"
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to quote the single quotes within the double quotes, otherwise you'll end up with literal quotes. Just try it with `echo`:

```
$ alias chrome="echo open -a \'google chrome\' "
$ chrome
open -a 'google chrome'
```

The quotes that are shown here are literal parts of the argument.

Just use one of:

```
alias chrome="open -a 'google chrome'"
alias chrome='open -a "google chrome"'
alias chrome="open -a \"google chrome\""
```

All of them are equivalent.

Comment: Your listing of all quoting options is helpful, but it's worth pointing out that using _double_-quoted strings for defining aliases is tricky, because the string may get expanded prematurely (at the time of alias _definition_ rather than _execution_).